# Windows demangling library

Tags: windows, visual-studio, demangler

I'm looking for an open source library to do Windows executable symbol name demangling. Does such a thing exist or must I use the Microsoft libraries?

Comment: What is the reason it must be open source, instead of using the functions in DBGHELP.DLL?

Comment: I need to be able to run on Linux as well.

Answer (score 2):

Uow, [this guy](http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-patches/2006-February/024077.html) seems to have nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a library as such, but I'd look at [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/), specifically the [debugger](http://cvs.winehq.org/cvsweb/wine/programs/winedbg/). I'm not sure but seems like a likely place to find code for that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that DbgHelp.dll should be the way to approach this.